# Create Active Directory User using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, active-directory, ldap

I have managed to query my Active Directory Domain Controller for user info using Zend_Ldap. But is it possible to, and in that case how do I, add a new user to the Active Directory using Zend Frameworks Zend_Ldap (or other php class that has this functionality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section "Adding data to the LDAP" in [the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.ldap.usage.html) is a good starter. ;-)

Comment: How come I ALWAYS miss the ONLY part of the Zend FW docs that have the info I'm looking for :)... Thanx m8